# Auth0 and Intuit SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, auth0, intuit-partner-platform

We are trying to setup SSO using the Intuit ID of our clients and our ID manager Auth0.

We have managed to set it up all up on the Intuit side but we cannot seem to find where should Intuit send the userID to auth0 to then trigger the auth flow on that side.

Here is a video demonstrating on it should work in principle:
https://youtu.be/iBL-JYWTecs?t=64

Does anybody have any insight on this?

Comment: I’ve tried to use https://marketplace.auth0.com/integrations/quickbooks-social-connection without success. Did you tried it?